# How to Manage User Access Level

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code for App_Code(Helper.cs)
My goal is to manage the user levels restricting the user from accessing the forms: Here is the code behind that I have created:

```
 public static void ValidateAccess(int[] usertypes)
{
    // Checks if the user has logged in already
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"] != null &&
        HttpContext.Current.Session["usertypeid"] != null)
    {
        int usertypeid = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["usertypeid"].ToString());

        if (usertypes.Contains(usertypeid))
        {
            // User is authorized to access the page.
        }
        else
        {
            // User is not authorized to access the page.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorized.aspx");
        }
    }
    else // if the user has not logged in yet
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?url" +
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

PageLoad Event

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Helper.ValidateAccess(new[] { 1 });
}
```

When I log in both user, they both redirect to NotAuthorize.aspx? Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: debug your code step by step - both sessions are null, or some of them is null, or the userid is not 1 or - how can we know that ? You will have spend less time if you debug your code step by step to find your problem rather making this question

Comment: What is `usertypes`? Put the Break Point at your inner `if` condition and check what value is in`usertypeid` and what are the values in `usertypes`. We can't debug your code, unfortunately you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: I already debug it one by one, but it seems that the code only get the number 2 usertype id.. I only have 2 user in the system (1) administrator (2) Secretary

Comment: Can you attach the screenshots of debugging?